# Memoir prints chapter endnotes as new chapter

Tags: memoir, pagenote

I am using memoir class to make a book and I want pagenotes to print at the end of each chapter.  Memoir is making them print as a separate chapter, numbered as if the notes constitute their own chapter.  This is not correct---I have never seen a book print chapter notes as a separate chapter.  How can I fix it so the notes print without triggering the chapter counter?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makepagenote
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
    \chapter{Title}
        Main text\pagenote{A note}
    \printpagenotes*
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) did you happen to look in the manual, page 250, `\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{%
  \chapter*{\notesname}
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\notesname}
}
`

Comment: It is a comment, I'll write an answer in a moment, then you can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the memoir manual, page 250,  essentially

```
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{%
  \chapter*{\notesname}
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\notesname}
}
```